# AnyDesk 6.0.1, keyboard Alt Gr combinations does not work from linux to linux

Tags: keyboard, linux-mint, raspberry-pi, anydesk

From any Linux Distro to any Linux Distro, with AnyDesk 6.0.1 and older versions, Alt Gr combinations does not work, for example is not possible to write: "€@#[]{}". In my specific case I use Linux Mint 20 to Raspberry Pi OS "raspios_full_armhf-2020-08-24". I have the same keyboard configuration in host and in the guest both.
Alt Gr work from Windows to Linux, from Linux to Windows and from Windows to Windows.
I have already submitted a ticket to AnyDesk support.
I haven't found anyone on the internet who has the same problem as me, but my co-workers have the same problem as me.
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't really have a solution, but thanks for your research because I am having exactly the same problem.

I operate my Raspberry Pi4 mostly with AnyDesk from other computers, and I thought it is a Raspberry issue that at least sometimes AltGR is not working. I ran raspbi-config to setup keyboard and make sure AltGR was taken into account, but to avail.

However, it seems I have exactly the same issue as you, it is specifically when I take an AnyDesk connection from my Linux Mint 20 PC to the RPi4, when AltGR does not work. If I take it from e.g. Windows 7, AltGR works just fine.

Heck, I just took an AnyDesk connection from my Linux Mint to Windows 7, and then from Windows 7 to Raspberry... and AltGR works through this two-hop rerouting. :D

So at least I know now there is something odd about the AnyDesk connection from Linux Mint 20 to Raspberry Pi4, causing AltGR not working... I've seen some other issues too, e.g. when I try to write a * on the RPi4 terminal, it starts spamming 8888888... characters repeatedly, and things like that.

I am currently using AnyDesk 6.0.1 but it seems there is a newer 6.1.1 version available too, I need to check if it has this same issue.

Comment: This should either be a comment or a new question with a link to this one. It is not allowed as an Answer because it does not answer the question.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately the system wouldn't allow me to comment on the original question, probably due to too low reputation score. Not sure why my rep is enough for "answers", but not for "comments".

Comment: As for making a new question, I think it would have been flagged as an unnecessary duplicate... Anyway I will try out newer AnyDesk, whether it has fixed this issue. I am just glad I found this discussion because I was fighting with the same problem, but had not figured out that this is some odd issue with an AnyDesk session specifically from a Linux system to Raspberry Pi4. Still many open questions, like if it is an issue with RPi4 version of AnyDesk, why does it still work if the session is from a Windows machine?

Comment: As for my "answer", I am fine if it will be deleted. Just to let the author know someone else is facing this issue too, when he wondered he doesn't see other online having the same issue...

Comment: Since I published this post, the problem has not yet been fixed.